# Передача байтового массива между TCPClient и TcpListener

Tags: c#, tcp-ip

Пытаюсь передать байтовый массив размером 1882374. Это текст некоторого текстового файла. Сервер и клиент вроде как работают исправно, клиент отдает данные, а сервер их получает. Но сервер получает не все данные а только 102295 из 1882374.

Код сервера:

```
try
{
    IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    // use local m/c IP address, and 
    // use the same in the client

    /* Initializes the Listener */
    TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(ipAd, 8001);

    /* Start Listeneting at the specified port */
    myList.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("The server is running at port 8001...");
    Console.WriteLine("The local End point is  :" +
                      myList.LocalEndpoint);
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.....");

    Socket s = myList.AcceptSocket();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection accepted from " + s.RemoteEndPoint);

    byte[] b = new byte[1882374];
    int k = s.Receive(b);
    Console.WriteLine("Recieved...");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

    UTF8Encoding asen = new UTF8Encoding();
    s.Send(asen.GetBytes("The string was recieved by the server."));
    Console.WriteLine("\nSent Acknowledgement");
    /* clean up */
    s.Close();
    myList.Stop();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

}

Код клиента:

```
byte[] datatoshare = TCPProcessor.datetoset;

try
{
    TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

    tcpclnt.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8001);
    // use the ipaddress as in the server program

    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    Console.Write("Enter the string to be transmitted : ");

    //String str = Console.ReadLine();
    Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

    //ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
    //byte[] ba = asen.GetBytes(str);
    byte[] ba = datatoshare;
    Console.WriteLine("Transmitting.....");

    stm.Write(ba, 0, ba.Length);

    byte[] bb = new byte[100];
    int k = stm.Read(bb, 0, 100);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(bb[i]));

    tcpclnt.Close();
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + e.StackTrace);
}
```

На сервере я убрал вывод полученого значения, я просто вывожу индекс по которому идет обращение к элементу переданого байтового массива, по этому вижу, что передает только 102295 из 1882374.
Может кто подказать в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что Read читает те байты, которые успели дойти. Оберните чтение (и запись) в BinaryReader/BinaryWriter и передавайте перед самими байтами длину массива.

Comment: Очередной вопрос с излишне легкомысленным подходом к TCP. Receive нужно вызывать несколько раз, пока он не считает все. Тупо обернуть весь сервер в try-catch, чтобы при обрыве с одним клиентом все падало - это тоже "класс".

Comment: понял, попробую, извините за дубликат(если такой есть), в следующий раз буду проверять был ли такой вопрос, перед тем как постить